# javascript-to display calendar in movable pop up

Tags: javascript

I want to display calendar every time in div tag which is movable pop up & user can select date from calendar in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jquery UI calendar control. Just include the JQUERY UI files to your HTML. Then

```
 <input type="text" name="cal" id="cal" />

 $("#cal").calendar();
```